# What is the difference between express validator 3.1.4 vs 5.3.0?

Tags: express, express-validator

What is the main difference between express validator 3.1.4 vs 5.3.0 ? I am confusing in versions of express validator.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the release for each version after 3.1.4: https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/releases

You can see there are a lot of differences.